# Strange log behavior - why the number "21" is added to the log.info's output?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The following Pine script:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
var int i = 0
log.info("i = {0} ", i)
i := i + 1
```

produces log output like the following. What is that "21" added to each value logged????

**Please note** that I am not asking how Pine script works. The laser focus of this question is why the number **"21"** is being added to the log output.

```
[2024-02-02T16:54:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,146

[2024-02-02T17:04:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,147

[2024-02-02T17:06:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,148

[2024-02-02T17:13:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,149

[2024-02-02T17:25:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,150

[2024-02-02T17:36:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,151

[2024-02-02T17:37:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,152

[2024-02-02T17:56:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,153

[2024-02-02T17:57:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,154

[2024-02-02T17:58:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,155

[2024-02-02T18:00:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,156

[2024-02-02T18:14:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,157

[2024-02-02T18:20:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,158

[2024-02-02T18:37:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,159

[2024-02-02T18:39:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,160

[2024-02-02T18:51:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,161

[2024-02-02T18:53:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,162

[2024-02-02T19:09:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,163

[2024-02-02T19:11:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,164

[2024-02-02T19:16:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,165

[2024-02-02T19:17:00.000-05:00]: i = 21,166
```

[image]

Comment: Could the value of `i` be between 21000 & 22000?

Comment: Only the last 10,000 messages will be displayed for historical bars; real-time messages are appended to those. https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-logs-in-pine-script-40490/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually 21 thousand.

Your script will be executed on each bar. And since you are using the `var` keyword on your `i`, it will keep its previous value and increment it on every bar making it essentially the same as `bar_index`.

You can see this with below code:

```
var int i = 0
log.info("\nbar_index: {0}\ni = {0} ", str.tostring(bar_index), i)
i := i + 1
```

[image]

And also, as stated [here](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-logs-in-pine-script-40490/):

> A timestamp prefixes each log entry. It is the bar’s opening time for
> historical bars, and the current time for real-time messages. Newer
> messages appear at the bottom of the pane. Only the last 10,000
> messages will be displayed for historical bars; real-time messages are
> appended to those.